# Saving and running wide_deep.py model

Tags: tensorflow

I've been playing around with the [Tensorflow Wide and Deep tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) using the census dataset.

The linear/wide tutorial states:

```
We will train a logistic regression model, and given an individual's information our model will output a number between 0 and 1
```

At the moment, I can't work out how to predict the output of an individual input (copied from the unit test):

```
TEST_INPUT_VALUES = {
    'age': 18,
    'education_num': 12,
    'capital_gain': 34,
    'capital_loss': 56,
    'hours_per_week': 78,
    'education': 'Bachelors',
    'marital_status': 'Married-civ-spouse',
    'relationship': 'Husband',
    'workclass': 'Self-emp-not-inc',
    'occupation': 'abc',
}
```

How can we predict and output whether this person is likely to earn <50k (0) or >=50k (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is [predict](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict), but I didn't figure out how to input one example data directly (I tried [numpy_input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn) and dict of tensors).

Instead, using the input function in `wide_deep.py` to write down the data into a temporary `csv` file then read it, the `predict` function can be used:

```
TEST_INPUT = ('18,Self-emp-not-inc,987,Bachelors,12,Married-civ-spouse,abc,'
              'Husband,zyx,wvu,34,56,78,tsr,<=50K')
# Create temporary CSV file
input_csv = '/tmp/census_model/test.csv'
with tf.gfile.Open(input_csv, 'w') as temp_csv:
    temp_csv.write(TEST_INPUT)

# restore model trained by wide_deep.py with same model_dir and model_type 
model = wide_deep.build_estimator(FLAGS.model_dir, FLAGS.model_type)
pred_iter = model.predict(input_fn=lambda: wide_deep.input_fn(input_csv, 1, False, 1))
for pred in pred_iter:
    # print(pred)
    print(pred['classes'])
```

There are other attributes like `probability`, `logits` etc in `pred`.

Comment: I added this code to the end of main (just taking out the `wide_deep.` prefix, and seems to do the trick: (I get an output of **[b'0']** or **[b'1']**).

Comment: One more thing confuses me: We are inputting either <=50K as the last variable, however isn't this what we are trying to predict? Or are we predicting the probability that the assertion that <=50K is accurate?

Comment: Do you guys know how to predict the results if there is no label column in the csv file? I found a thread here, but didn't work out for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948172/predict-in-tensorflow-estimator-using-input-fn

Comment: @Blair I tried this input: `TEST_INPUT = ('18,Self-emp-not-inc,987,Bachelors,12,Married-civ-spouse,abc,'
              'Husband,zyx,wvu,34,56,78,tsr,')`, it works too.

Answer (score 1):

Hookay, I can answer this now.. So if you want to evaluate the test set accuracy, you can follow the accepted answer, but if you want to make your own predictions, here are the steps.

First, construct a new `input_fn`, notice you need to alter the columns and the default column values since the label column wouldn't be there.

```
def parse_csv(value):
    print('Parsing', data_file)
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=_PREDICT_COLUMNS_DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(_PREDICT_COLUMNS, columns))

    return features


def predict_input_fn(data_file):
    assert tf.gfile.Exists(data_file), ('%s not found. Please make sure the path is correct.' % data_file)

    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=5)
    dataset = dataset.batch(1) # => This is very important to get the rank correct
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features = iterator.get_next()
    return features
```

Then you can just call it simply by

```
results = model.predict(
        input_fn=lambda: predict_input_fn(data_file='test.csv')
    )
```